# Does SQL Server Management Studio 2008 Activity Monitor work with SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am trying to use SQL Server Management Studio 2008's Activity Monitor with an SQL Server 2000 instance to diagnose some query performance issues. I can connect SMSS 2008 to the db fine, and use it to browse objects and run queries. But when I press the Activity Monitor button, it pops up an error message saying:

> Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>   This operation does not support
>   connections to Microsoft SQL Server
>   Personal Edition version 8.00.818.

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175518.aspx) implies that Activity Monitor works with SQL Server 2000. Is it the fact that it's Personal Edition that's preventing it from working? The error message isn't clear whether it's the edition or version that's the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it does not -  the verbiage in [Books online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175518.aspx) appears misleading

Comment: I can confirm that this does not work when I try to connect from Management Studio 2008 Activity Monitor to my SQL Server 2000 Enterprise instance.

Comment: Agreed.  I even have a hard time getting it to work with SQL 2005.

Answer (score 1):

I have a SQL 2000 Enterprise database, can confirm that I can SELECT from sysprocesses and syslocks and get "This operation does not support connections to Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition version 8.00.2039." when trying open Activity Monitor.

I presume that the MSDN article is incorrect. And it likely does not work due to the absence of DMV's.